# excel vba set range as currentregion

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set a range equal to a currentregion. The code below works, but the activate command changes focus which I don't want. If I remove the activate command excel crashes on the last line. The code below is in a class module and a portion of a larger sub. Any suggestions?

```
worksheets(SHT).activate  'stops the runtime error but changes sheet  
With Worksheets(SHT)
        With .Range(TBL2).CurrentRegion
            .Cells = Data
        End With
    End With
```

[image: runtime error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of code missing but you can transfer the contents of a 2 dimensioned variant array (e.g. *Data*) into the current region using something like this.

```
With Worksheets(SHT)
    With .Range(TBL2).CurrentRegion
        .Cells = Data
    End With
End With
```

Since there is no guarantee that *Data* and the .CurrentRegion are the same size, this might be better as,

```
With Worksheets(SHT)
    With .Range(TBL2).resize(ubound(Data, 1), ubound(Data, 2))
        .Cells = Data
    End With
End With
```

It is hard to be more precise given that the extents of the *Data* 2-D array are unknown.

**Tested with:**

```
Sub collect_change_dump()
    Dim SHT As String, TBL2 As String, v As Long, w As Long, Data As Variant
    SHT = "Sheet1"
    TBL2 = "D3"
    With Worksheets(SHT)
        With .Range(TBL2).CurrentRegion
            Data = .Cells.Value
        End With
        For v = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
            For w = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
                Data(v, w) = "blah"
            Next w
        Next v
        With .Range(TBL2).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2))
            .Cells = Data
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, the first code works well and much neater. fyi the arrays will be the same size as other code extracts the data, manipulates it and then pastes it back into a worksheet using this sub.

Comment: Glad you got sorted out. Just ran some quick tests and the ranks (e.g. *1* and *2*) for the resize are in the correct order.

Comment: unfortunately there is still a bug. If the cursor is on the tab I want to copy data to (the correct sheet is active) the code works. But if a different tab is active then excel crashes?? The spreadsheet worked fine in excel v2010, but I have updated laptop and software and now running it in v2013. I also have problems with a userform which could be related. Any suggestions?

Comment: if i add `worksheets(SHT).activate` to the start of the code I don't get the runtime error......any idea why?

Comment: I've just tried this on XL 2013 with several worksheets and had no trouble. I haven't tried it on more than one workbook though and locating the worksheet could be an issue with that. See my bench-test code above.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do. Activating the worksheet before dumping the data stops the runtime error, but changes focus to a different worksheet than the one I am working on which is not preferable.